# Scrape Table Data with navigation using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I tried downloading pdf files from the website, which is contained in a table with pagination. I can download the pdf files from the first page, but it is not fetching the pdf from all the 4000+ pages. When I tried understanding the logic by observing the URL request, it seems static with out any additional value get appended on it during pagination and I couldn't figure out the way to fetch all pdfs from the table using BeautifulSoup.

Hereby attached the code that I am using to download pdf file from the table in website,

```
# Import libraries
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import requests, json
  
# URL from which pdfs to be downloaded


url="https://loksabha.nic.in/Questions/Qtextsearch.aspx"
  
# Requests URL and get response object
response = requests.get(url)
  
# Parse text obtained


span = soup.find("span", id="ContentPlaceHolder1_lblfrom")
Total_pages = re.findall(r'\d+', span.text) 
print(Total_pages[0])
# Find all hyperlinks present on webpage
# links = soup.find_all('a')
i = 0
  
# From all links check for pdf link and
# if present download file
# for link in links:

for link in table1.find_all('a'):
    if ('.pdf' in link.get('href', [])):
      
        list2 = re.findall('CalenderUploading', link.get('href', []))
        if  len(list2)==0:
            # url = re.findall('hindi', link.get('href', []))
            print(link.get('href', []))
            i += 1
            # Get response object for link
            response = requests.get(link.get('href'))
            # Write content in pdf file
            pdf = open("pdf"+str(i)+".pdf", 'wb')
            pdf.write(response.content)
            pdf.close()
            print("File ", i, " downloaded")
  
           
print("All PDF files downloaded")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Firstly

you need to establish a session first time you call to store cookie values

sess=requests.session()

and use sess.get subsequently instead of requests.get

- Secondly:

its not static... its not get request for subsequent pages

its a post request with  : ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtpage="2" for page 2

make a session with requests
capture the view parameters after first request using BeautifulSoup

the value of __VIEWSTATE, __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR and __EVENTVALIDATION

etc are  in a `<div class="aspNetHidden">`

when you request for tthe page for first time...

for subsequent pages you will have to pass these parameters along with
page number  in post parameter like this ... ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtpage="2"

using "POST" and not "GET"

this is what is sent by post request for eg. for page 4001 page here
on the loksabha site

[image]

workout other parts .. dont expect complete solution here :-)

```
sess=requests.session()
resp=sess.get('https://loksabha.nic.in/Questions/Qtextsearch.aspx')
soup=bs(resp.content)
vstat=soup.find('input',{'name':'__VIEWSTATE'})['value']
vstatgen=soup.find('input',{'name':'__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR'})['value']
vstatenc=soup.find('input',{'name':'__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED'})['value']
eventval=soup.find('input',{'name':'__EVENTVALIDATION'})['value']

for pagenum in range(4000): # change as per your old code
    
    postback={'__EVENTTARGET': 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$cmdNext',
    '__EVENTARGUMENT': '',
    '__VIEWSTATE':vstat,
    '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': vstatgen,
    '__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED': vstatenc,
    '__EVENTVALIDATION': eventval,
    'ctl00$txtSearchGlobal':  '',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlfile': '.pdf',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TextBox1': '',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btn': 'allwordbtn',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btn1': 'titlebtn',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtpage': str(pagenum) }

    resp=sess.post('https://loksabha.nic.in/Questions/Qtextsearch.aspx',data=postback)
    soup=bs(resp.content)
    vstat=soup.find('input',{'name':'__VIEWSTATE'})['value']
    vstatgen=soup.find('input',{'name':'__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR'})['value']
    vstatenc=soup.find('input',{'name':'__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED'})['value']
    eventval=soup.find('input',{'name':'__EVENTVALIDATION'})['value']

    ### process next page...extract pdfs here
    ###
    ###
    ####
```

Comment: jsn, thank you for the idea, does that mean I need to send request separately for all the 4000+ pages? if possible could you explain with the sample code ?

Comment: request the First page. take out all pdfs,  now using beautiful soup find this `<div class="aspNetHidden">`  inside this find <input> tags. there you will find __VIEWSTATE, __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR and __EVENTVALIDATION values.  now request post these values as data along with those given in picture posted above which includes the page number. and you will get next page and again and again till you reach last page. Thats a lot of code

Comment: @jsn what is nextpage in the code , i think you meant pagnum